# selectRaw for MONTH(created_at) doesn't work running a test

Tags: laravel, database, testing, eloquent

I have a function in Laravel 10 User model that calculates an AVG of calculations monthly and this on a view. It works fine for my application, but when I run a test with assertStatus of this view, an error is shown.

```
    public function numCalculationsAvgMonth(): string
    {
        $data = NumberOfCalculations::where('user_id', $this->id)
            ->selectRaw('
                count(id) as data,
                YEAR(created_at) as year,
                MONTH(created_at) as month
            ')
            ->groupby('year', 'month')
            ->get()
            ->avg('data');

        return decimals($data, 2);
    }
```

The result of my test is the next:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: YEAR (Connection: sqlite, SQL: select 
                count(id) as data,
                YEAR(created_at) as year,
                MONTH(created_at) as month
             from "number_of_calculations" where "user_id" = 1 group by "year", "month")
```

I need to use a trait in my TestCase?

Comment: The solution is pretty easy and should be this: always use the production database engine, do not use something different because it takes less time, you must replicate the production environment when you run tests, else you have like 50% in but you are missing another important 50%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "no such function: YEAR" indicates that the test environment simply does not support the YEAR() function used in the selectRaw() method. One solution is to use the strftime() function instead, which is supported by SQLite and can be used to extract the year and month from a date.

Here's a possible version of the numCalculationsAvgMonth() function that uses strftime() and returns a float instead of a string:

```
public function numCalculationsAvgMonth(): float
{
    $data = NumberOfCalculations::where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->selectRaw('count(id) as data, strftime("%Y", created_at) as year, strftime("%m", created_at) as month')
        ->groupBy('year', 'month')
        ->get()
        ->avg('data');

    return round($data, 2);
}
```

Comment: Excellent (again) and thanks,  it really does help use of the site when questions are clearly answered. Cheers.